# What is the "identity string" of my certificate (mac + codesign utility)?

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain, codesign

I'm gonna say this right away:  I have no idea what I'm doing here.  I am not a mac developer.

Here's the scenario:  I have an installer (.pkg) that my boss wants me to sign.  I have a certificate, issued by Thawte; which I've imported into the keychain program (and set it to be trusted for everything).  In package maker, under the configuration tab, there is a label that says "Certificate", and directly next to it another that reads "not supported".  Well, great.

So, codesign; says it can't sign .pkgs, but can sign .dmgs... but I have to give it an identifier string so it can pull my certificate from the keychain.  But I see in no place a field called "identity" or "identifier" or anything of the like when scouring the keychain program.

I feel really dumb about this;  I've been at this for a few hours, google has yielded a number of useful things, but none of them explain where I find the "identifier" string :P

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The identifier is the "Common Name" from your certificate. Please refer to [OS X code signing](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Developer/2008/02/11/Mac-OS-X-Application-Code-Signing.html) or [Apple's Code Signing In Dept](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2206.html)

Comment: Awesome!  I see what my problem is now.  Thanks =)