# codesign: "Argument list too long"

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain, codesign

In the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523487/what-is-the-identity-string-of-my-certificate-mac-codesign-utility), I had to codesign a .dmg file.

The old certificate has since expired, and I have a new one to sign with.  No problem, right?  Do what I did last time?  Yes.  I exported the new certificate chain and private key as a .pfx file, in windows.  It would seem I can import that directly into the OS X keychain tool, without converting to .p12 first.  So I did.

When it comes time to actually codesign, first try says it can't determine which certificate to use.  So I put the old certificate chain and private key into one keychain (2011), and the new ones in another (2012), and try again:

so...

`codesign -s "Identifier Name" --keychain 2012.keychain --verbose --dryrun somefile.dmg`

Returns...

`somefile.dmg: signed  []`

BUT!

`codesign -s "Identifier Name" --keychain 2012.keychain --verbose somefile.dmg`

Returns...

`somefile.dmg:  Argument list too long`

And just to be sure...

`codesign -d --verbose somefile.dmg`

Reveals...

`somefile.dmg:  code object is not signed`

And for kicks and giggles,

`codesign -s "Identifier Name" --keychain 2011.keychain --verbose somefile.dmg`

Reveals...

`somefile.dmg: signed generic [somefile.dmg]`

**tl;dr** I can still sign things ok with my expired certificate, but when I try to do so with the new one, it works on a dryrun, but when I try to sign for real, the command returns "argument list too long".

I've been trying to figure this out for about two weeks now I kid you not, and as far I can find from searching, there is nothing to be found on this mysterious error message.

Any ideas as to what is going on, or what more I can do?

Thanks,

-Lunpa

Comment: Something of a curiosity,both the dry run and normal failures return an exit code of 256 =P

Comment: Though, I have low expectations for this to get solved at this point =)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem in OSX 10.6.8.

Fortunately, it looks like running the same command in 10.7 Lion worked fine.