# How much does it cost to get a code signing certificate from Apple?

Tags: macos

Due to [mysteries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232908/codesign-argument-list-too-long) preventing me from using a certificate issued by thawte from code signing a DMG file, and the need for some expediency,  I'm going to try to convince my boss to get us a development license with apple.  If nothing else, there is at least product support...?  Anyways:

I gather that the developer's license is $100/year.  Beyond that, what does it cost to have them issue a certificate for code signing?

Answer (score 5):

Your $100.00 developer account will let you create as many certificates as you need for one or multiple apps.  For IOS you typically create provisioning licenses for development, so that your test users can try your app before apple approves it.  This isn't needed on the Mac however.  You should be able to just build your app and deploy it however you like without Apple being involved.

You don't say in your post, but I'm assuming that you are planning to sell the application through the Mac App Store?  If you are planning to use the App Store, or Mac App Store, when you are ready to publish your app, you create another signing certificate, used only when you submit for review.  If you are self publishing, be aware that the certificates Apple issues typically have short expiration dates, and you may have to re-sign your distribution bundle in a few months.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was looking for.  We are not planning on selling anything over the app store, but rather signing a dmg containing an installer for a browser plugin =P

An expiration period of a few months I think would be ok, considering the certificates are free.

Answer (score 4):

I had a hard time finding anything concrete on Apple websites, but looking bellow on the sites I found, it sure seems you have to pay Apple to get your app signed, even if it won't go in the Mac App Store. I didn't thought you need to pay for that. It sucks for open source apps. :/

http://www.realsoftwareblog.com/2012/08/code-signing-real-studio-apps-on.html

> Unfortunately, to sign your apps you need a developer certificate from
>   Apple.  And the only way to get a Developer Certificate is to sign up
>   for the Mac Developer Program, which costs $100 a year.  However, the
>   certificate you get is good for 5 years, so it looks like you do not
>   need to pay the $100 fee each year unless you also want to distribute
>   apps in the Mac App Store.

http://successfulsoftware.net/2012/08/30/how-to-sign-your-mac-os-x-app-for-gatekeeper/

> 1. Sign up for Apple Developer Connection ($99 per year). Doesn’t matter if you already paid through the nose for a Windows authenticode
>      certificate. Gatekeeper only accepts Apple certificates, so you have
>      no choice. On the plus side, you do get other benefits, including
>      downloading new OS upgrades for free.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/315419-how-to-get-mac-codesign-certificate.html

> You need to buy it from a certificate authority, like Thawte or
>   Verisign (or one of the myriad resellers) and they will all be happy
>   to sell you one at prices that range from around $80 to around
>   $500/yr. Alternatively, you can get a certificate from Apple as part
>   of the OS X Developer Program, which will cost you the extra $100/yr
>   but also includes beta access to OS X system software.
>
> ...
>
> Prior to Mountain Lion, the only advantage of buying a cert from a
>   known authority is for the firewall system preference "Automatically
>   allow signed software to receive incoming connections" (which by the
>   way is a really stupid preference, IMO). The disadvantage of such
>   certs is that they usually expire relatively quickly, in one or two
>   years.
>
> Mountain Lion changes the game a bit. It eliminates a lot of the
>   advantage of 3rd party cert authorities, because only Apple's cert
>   will allow your app to run, so if you're not going to get a cert from
>   Apple (I don't think I can discuss the terms here), you might as well
>   self-sign.

Comment: It's truly amazing how hard it is to find this information on Apple's awful website.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the cheapest for 1 year is $200 but it get it also at $500 from Symantec :)

https://www.sslshopper.com/apple-code-signing-certificates.html